# Delete Parent Div to correctly display Form Input Element without Styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on my first App with Phonegap and the prototype I have started with also includes JQuery Mobile, which happily makes eveything look very mobile, but sadly hinders me to flexibly place this Input Form and especially change the style.
In my index.html the input form is placed like this:

```
<input type="search" name="search-mini" id="search-mini" value="" data-mini="true">
```

When I inspect the Form again on the Webpage with the Inspector it is suddenly wrapped by a div that created all the formatting trouble:

```
<div class="ui-input-search ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-mini ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear"></div>
```

How can I get rid of all the formatting by this div? Unwrap somehow? The answer is propably simple...but I know nothing about jQuery and all and I did not find the answer. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add data-role="none" to the elements that you do not want styled. That tells jQuery not to style those particular objects. See the documentation at [jQuery Doc](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0.1/docs/forms/docs-forms.html)